# Space of using range(n)

Tags: python, range

Could you tell me please, if I use `for i in range(n)`, does python creates a range of 0 .. n-1, and iterates elements in this container (O(n) extra space), or it use only 1 vatiable (O(1)) space)

From one side, I thought, if we can convert range to list, then using range function creates a container (O(n)).but from the other side, instead of using `for i in range(n)`, we can use `while i < n ...` O(1).

Comment: note, `range` *does create a container*. It's just one that occupies constant space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, `range` does not create all the elements, but only returns the current element when you request it. So yes, it's using O(1) space.

Comment: I'm sure it has to store the context for the call, like start, step, end, and the last emitted value. But since those aren't proportional to the input, it's O(1) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's O(1): the range object doesn't store the values it yields.

As the [Python documentation explains](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

> The advantage of the `range` type over a regular `list` or `tuple` is that a `range` object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the `start`, `stop` and `step` values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed).

Of course, if you make a list with the contents of the range, the list does use O(N) space.

Answer (score 2):

This was one of the big changes between Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2, `range` created a full list, but you could avoid creating a list by instead using `xrange`.  So in Python 2, you'd do `for i in xrange(...)` to efficiently iterate over a range without creating a temporary list.

In Python 3, this was changed so that `range` behaves like the Python 2 `xrange`. To get the Python 2 range behavior in Python 3, i.e. to create the full list, you can do `list(range(...))`, but of course you want to avoid that unless you truly need the list.